# how to solve java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/curator/RetryPolicy in storm

Tags: apache-storm, apache-kafka

How can i solve

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Preconditions
>   at
>   org.apache.curator.ensemble.fixed.FixedEnsembleProvider.(FixedEnsembleProvider.java:39)
>   at org.apache.curator.framework.

and

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/curator/RetryPolicy

in storm-kafka integration.

I am using:

- kafka_2.9.2-0.8.1.1
- Zookeeper - 3.4.6
- Storm - 0.9.3

updated

pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-reflect</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
        <artifactId>storm-kafka</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka_2.9.2</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.zookeeper</groupId>
        <artifactId>zookeeper</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.6</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
        <artifactId>storm-core</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
        <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: if you are usnig maven .. can u share your `pom.xml`

Comment: can you please try changing 
`<artifactId>kafka_2.9.2</artifactId>`
To 
`<artifactId>kafka_2.10</artifactId>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following lines in your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.curator</groupId>
  <artifactId>curator-test</artifactId>
  <version>2.4.0</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.jboss.netty</groupId>
      <artifactId>netty</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

For `org/apache/curator/RetryPolicy`, you should use

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.curator</groupId>
  <artifactId>curator-client</artifactId>
  <version>2.11.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Note for ZooKeeper `3.4.6`, the latest version (as of this post) compatible for Curator is `2.11.0`.

However `curator-client` also needs `curator-framework`. So you might want to add

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.curator</groupId>
  <artifactId>curator-framework</artifactId>
  <version>2.11.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: <version>2.11.0</scope> should be <version>2.11.0</version>